# Kill a hung webistrano deployment

Tags: capistrano, webistrano

I'm currently trying to set up deployment using Webistrano/Capistrano. Due to a permission error, my test deployment has not completed. However, because it failed before the deployment pid was created the cancel button does not appear in the Webistrano deployment interface.

I'm wondering how I can kill the deployment process and unlock the deployment stage (I assume there is a pid file or something somewhere on my system). Webistrano's running via Passenger through Apache on a Centos5 machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kill the hung deployment simply change the status of the deployment in the 'deployments' db table. You'll also have to unlock the deployment stage by updating the 'stages' table and set the 'locked' column to 0.